# How would you combine several logos in an educational cover?

Tags: logo, legal, trademark

I have created a combination of several logos as a cover for an educational program in which the teaching material involves all the topics shown by the trademarks. It occurred to me that there might be guidelines restricting such act from trademark owners.  I saw guidelines from one of the trademark owners, Docker, for example:

> Our word Marks (but not logo marks or other graphic depictions of our Marks) may be used in an informational context to name or describe the subject matter of an educational or informational program, to refer to Docker product or technology, provided however that such use otherwise complies with these Guidelines and the following requirements:
> The Docker mark is used only in a referential context or for naming Docker or to indicate compatibility, and not in a title of a program, domain name, website, product or service
> The use must not falsely imply or suggest a sponsorship or endorsement by, a license from, or a partnership or affiliation with Docker.
> Any printed or online materials relating to the program must include proper attribution statements, registration symbols such as ® or © as appropriate, and a trademark notice statement in a form that we provide or approve.
> It seems pretty strict, isn't it? -   [Docker Trademark Guidelines](https://www.docker.com/legal/trademark-guidelines)

Besides the legal aspect, which I should discuss with a lawyer as duly mentioned by Billy Kerr, are there any general guidelines on how to design such covers like A vs. B or Learning A,B,C, and D?
If you were to do a similar job, how would you do it to prevent copyright claims and still convey a strong meaning on the topics involved?

Comment: I've voted to close this as off-topic since the question appears to be asking for legal advice. Ask a lawyer instead. Sorry about that.

Comment: Do you think it would be better suited for law.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Maybe, however I'm not sure if they will give free legal advice either, just as we don't offer free design work on GDSE.  Perhaps if you change the wording it might be less objectionable.

Comment: Yes, the wording seems a mess currently.  Thanks for your take.

Comment: Another option might be to contact the trademark owner and ask for permission. They will either say yes or no. Asking never hurts.

Comment: if your educational material is _about_ the referred brands / products I suppose you should mention somehow in the cover, noted the exceptions mentioned by the brand owners. How to create that cover is entirely up to you, but the rest of your question is still a legal question.